# What's the closest equivalent to JavaScript's grouping operator in Python 2.7 destructuring assignment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, destructuring

In JavaScript I can choose to be agnostic of the complete structure of some returned value during destructured assignment:

```
const returnsFour = () => [1, 2, 3, 4];

const [ a, b, ...c ] = returnsFour();
```

Now `a` is `1` and `b` is `2` and `c` contains whatever else was in that Array.

**Can I do anything like this in Python 2.7?**

A naive translation doesn't work, because the `*` operator only works to group stuff when in a function signature:

```
returnsFour = lambda: (1, 2, 3, 4)

a, b, *c = returnsFour()  # syntax error
```

The next thing I would try is just grabbing indices of the result, but this is less pretty when you want several different indices as variables.

```
results = returnsFour()
a = results[0]
b = results[1]
```

Comment: Simply use Python 3? Works there.

Comment: You can use the star operator like that in Py3: `a, b, *c = returnsFour()`.

Comment: Thanks all, looks like the answer is "no" and "use python 3", will accept if someone posts...

Comment: A super silly hack just because I wanted to see how super silly it would look :-) `a, b, c = (lambda a, b, *c: (a, b, c))(*returnsFour())`